# Fuseki concurrency

Tags: concurrency, jena, ontology, fuseki

I am working on a project where I am using Apache Jena Fuseki 2.4 as the graph storage. Anyone knows what is the maximum concurrent read operations that Fuseki supports?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2.4 is quite old. It was released 2016-05-10. The current version is 4.1 (aligned to the Jena version).

Comment: The default is 20 threads (for Fuseki main). It is configurable vai a Jetty confiuration file or if a WAR file, it's controlled by the webapp container (e.g. Tomcat). The practical limit of concurrent read is more dependent by the server hardware and the nature of the queries.

Comment: Thanks @AndyS for the inputs. 

This 20 thread is for what hardware configurations. I am mostly looking for read concurrency. 

Also this numbers varies with latest fuseki versions?

Comment: That refers to the latest version.